# What adjustments need to be made before a Monte-Carlo simulation can be applied for the exotic option $(L_{\text{domestic}}-L_{\text{foreign}})^{+}$

Tags: options, black-scholes, interest-rates, monte-carlo, pricing

I just want to reassure myself that I understand why Monte-Carlo is the appropriate tool in computing the fair value prices for different options. Let's say we have a Tenor discretization $T_{0}=0<T_{1}< T_{2}$ and some numeraire $N(T_{2};t)=P(T_{2};t)$, i.e. the domestic zero coupon bond that matures at $T_{2}$.

Say we have a risky domestic forward rate $L_{\text{domestic}}$, foreign forward rate $L_{\text{foreign}} (T_{1},T_{2};t):=L_{\text{foreign}}(t)$ and a forward FX rate $FFX(t)$. $FFX$ and $L_{\text{domestic}}$ are martingales under the equivalent martingale measure associated to $N(T_{2};t):=N(t)$ and that all three of the processes follow a log-normal process under $\mathbb Q^{P(T_{2})}$

What adjustments need to be made before a Monte-Carlo simulation can be applied for the exotic option $(L_{\text{domestic}}(T_{1})-L_{\text{foreign}}(T_{1}))^{+}$ under the measure $\mathbb Q ^{P(T_{2})}$?

My thoughts, $\left((L_{\text{domestic}}(t)-L_{\text{foreign}}(t))^{+}\right)_{0\leq t \leq T_{2}}$ is not even tradeable in the domestic market such that

$$\frac{(L_{\text{domestic}}(t)-L_{\text{foreign}}(t))^{+}}{N(t)}$$ is not a $\mathbb Q^{P(t_{2})}$ martingale. So we cannot use the universal pricing formula:

$V(0) = N(0)\mathbb E ^{\mathbb Q ^{P(T_{2})}}[\frac{(L_{\text{domestic}}(T_{1})-L_{\text{foreign}}(T_{1}))^{+}}{N(T_{1})}]$.

Any ideas on how to progress since I cannot use the above formula?

Comment: Monte Carlo simulation is not a model, it's a method that can be applied on a model to find solutions. So the real question is what model to use so that your Monte Carlo simulation of the SDE will provide sound results. What that model will be will depend on what your underlying (forwards rates) are. Commodities, interest rates, equities will all be priced differently. Is this a purely academic question or for actual pricing? If it's the latter, it may be worth to check if you have access to tools that can price it properly (Bloomberg and the like).

Comment: @AKdemy It's an academic exercise. Forward rates are on interest rates.